# What are most vintage claw foot bath tubs made of and are they still safe to use?

Tags: bathtub

- What are most vintage claw foot bath tubs made from ?
- Any concerns with the inner tub being worn/chipped, in regards to chemicals
  or veneers leaking out when in use... or does it have to be refinished ?
- In this specific case will be using it as an ice bath and no plumbing connected. Any issues with using water\ice in the 45-55F range?

Comment: Most are made from cast iron with an enamel baked on finish.  The enamel protects the cast iron from rusting.  About the only issue I would have using it for an ice bath, is that it is cold.  If the cast iron is showing, then it should at be at least protected with a good paint.  Imagine the tub not looking like new is not an issue.

Comment: Crip659 answers go below , are they safe ? As safe as any other cast iron and enamel sink or tub , I know the sinks are still made but haven’t seen a tub probably due to costs.

Answer (score 3):

Most are made from cast iron with an enamel baked on finish.

The enamel protects the cast iron from rusting. If the cast iron is showing, then it should at be at least protected with a good paint. Imagine the tub not looking like new is not an issue.

About the only issue I would have using it for an ice bath, is that it is cold.  Cast iron bathtubs are known for holding the water temperature longer(at least for warm water), than the new thinly made tubs.  Do not think there are any concerns of chemicals/offgasing, even if they are chipped.  The chips might be sharp enough to cut if not removed(loose chips).

Comment: And the cast iron is not tough so low temperatures do not make it less tough like a typical carbon steel,

Comment: The only "unsafe" possibility is that continued exposure of bare cast iron to water will hasten the rusting process leading to a leak.

Comment: Evidently lead may be an issue. Presumably (at least as I understand the normal chemistry, but perhaps there was such as thing as lead enamel back in the day?) not with the original enamel, but more obviously likely if repainted. Not something I've looked into personally, but a friend got another friend's old clawfoot (with lead) because they felt that leaving it in the house they were selling was going to cause a problem with the sale, and they claimed it was a common to nearly universal  issue with old clawfoot tubs. So perhaps it really is the enamel itself... Or I've been misinformed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Interesting about the lead.  Think that even with soaking in a tub that has lead leaching, would be very low concern, drinking the water would be much different, raising the concern a lot higher.

Comment: @crip659  Not really in the habit of drinking bath water.. lol   :-)  +